# loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable sqrt method

Tags: python, pandas, typeerror, normalization, attributeerror

I made a function, for z_score_normalization as

```
# z_score normalization

def z_score_normalization(X):
    X = np.array(X)
    mu = np.mean(X, axis = 0)
    sigma = np.std(X, axis = 0)
    X_norm = (X - mu)/sigma
    
    return X_norm, mu, sigma
```

When I call this function for my data X, It gives me TypeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'sqrt'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[317], line 2
      1 # normalize the original features
----> 2 X_norm, X_mu, X_sigma = z_score_normalization(X)
      3 print(f"X_mu = {X_mu}, \n\nX_sigma = {X_sigma}")
      4 print("\n")

Cell In[316], line 6, in z_score_normalization(X)
      4 X = np.array(X)  # Ensure X is a numpy array
      5 mu = np.mean(X, axis=0)
----> 6 sigma = np.std(X, axis=0)
      7 # Handle the case where standard deviation is zero or near zero
      8 sigma[sigma < 1e-6] = 1.0  # Set to a small nonzero value

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in std(*args, **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py:3605, in std(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims, where)
   3602     else:
   3603         return std(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof, **kwargs)
-> 3605 return _methods._std(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
   3606                      **kwargs)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/_methods.py:273, in _std(a, axis, dtype, out, ddof, keepdims, where)
    269 ret = _var(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
    270            keepdims=keepdims, where=where)
    272 if isinstance(ret, mu.ndarray):
--> 273     ret = um.sqrt(ret, out=ret)
    274 elif hasattr(ret, 'dtype'):
    275     ret = ret.dtype.type(um.sqrt(ret))

TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type float which has no callable sqrt method
```

I was trying to Normalize my Data feautres. I was expecting it to be correct.
When I run this code on Jupyter notebook It was running perfectly with no error.
But When I run the same code on Kaggle notebook, This error occurred.

Comment: Are you sure X is an array of floating point numbers?

Comment: Ohh, Yes now it solved.. By modifying type of X.  (X = np.array(X, dtype = 'float'))  Thanks!!